# MySQLi insert string dies at & character

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I have been fighting with a database insert problem most of the day now, so now its time to seek help.

I have a comment form on my site which is submitted and processed via ajax, 9 times out of 10 it will work flawlessly but I have noticed that when you enter the `&` character, it ends the string prematurely but still inserts the string to database before that character!

In my comments section, I allow snippets of code to be posted and highlighted when displayed on page, so the `&` character is pretty much needed for comparison purposes in any posted snippets.

I'm using a MySQLi class, the escape function is just a basic real_escape, and mynl2br is just a custom nl2br function, this is the code that inserts the comment data to database:

```
$name = $db->escape($_POST['name']);
$email = $db->escape($_POST['email']);
$url = $db->escape($_POST['web']);
$comment = $db->escape(mynl2br($_POST['comments']));
$script_id = $db->escape($_POST['script_id']);

$insertData = array(
    '`author`' => ''.$name.'',
    '`email`' => ''.$email.'',
    '`url`' => ''.$url.'',
    '`comment`' => ''.$comment.'',
    '`script_id`' => ''.$script_id.'',
    '`time`' => ''.time().''
);

if ($db->insert('script_comments', $insertData)) {
    // sent success response back
    exit;   
}
```

can anyone understand why the & character is prematurely ending the comment string?

Comment: How are you encoding the `&` on the client side?

Comment: Since this has a mysqli tag on it, i'm guessing your using mysqli...I'm not familar with the ->escape function, but I am familiar with `$mysqli->real_escape_string(`... because I don't think your string is being properly escape'd

Comment: Are you using GET or POST to submit the AJAX? You might need to urlencode your data before submitting it

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson comment string isnt encoded on client side

Comment: @ j. Robertson thats all it is, but its enclosed in the escape function

Comment: Gotcha. I still suspect it's not being escaped correctly - Might be worth trying to use prepared statements and see if the problem persists.

Comment: its just strange that every other special character seems to be escaped properly except the &. i also tried encodeURIComponent on client side, and also tried urlencode on server side but still no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ajax request is sending the data via a GET request (that should be POST), and the data isn't properly escaped with `encodeURIComponent()` on the javascript side. Your PHP script looks good so far.

Comment: its using the post method

Comment: But the "&" still is a special characterand needs escaping. You should show us the Ajax part, it is the first thing that can go wrong, and based on the character that messes things up, it is likely to have the fault.

Comment: it seems that the server-side tampering of the string was undoing the client-side tampering, i stripped out all string manipulation on both sides and started again with encodeURIComponent and hey presto, it worked! thanks for all your input guys!